# select list displayed with authrority not with id role in grails

Tags: grails-2.0

i have two class role and user 
package tachemanagement.secu

class Role {

```
String authority

static hasMany = [users: User]
static mapping = {
    cache true
}

static constraints = {

    authority(nullable:true)

}
```

}
package tachemanagement.secu

class User {

```
transient springSecurityService
static belongsTo = [rol: Role]


String username
String password
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired


static transients = ['springSecurityService']

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, unique: true
    password blank: false
}

static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}
protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}
```

}

*

i want to display a select list from role in user form

but the list displayed with name of id role (1,2,3) haw can be displayed with authority not just with id ?

Answer (score 0):

Use toString() method in Role like the following

```
class Role{

    String authority

    static hasMany = [users: User]
    static mapping = {
          cache true
    }

    static constraints = {

          authority(nullable:true)

    }
    String toString() {
         "$authority"
    }
}
```